# SSRS - Get the max time for the max date from a list of dates

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report with a `dataset` that queries `AS400`. I am trying to print a "Version number" on the top of my report. Due to several complications, I cannot really print a version number better than last update time.

This is my what my data looks like:

1. The query takes a parameter that is a `PackingDate`. As in, the `ShopOrders` were written to pack on this date.
2. The query returns anywhere from 10-25 shop orders for each `PackingDate`.
3. Each of these shop orders have 4 columns: `DateCreated`, `TimeCreated`, `DateModified`, `TimeModified`.
4. Shop orders go through changes and revisions frequently. Every time a shop order is changed, the `DateModified`, `TimeModified` field changes.
5. I want to look at each of these shop orders, look at the `DateModified`, get the maximum date, then look at the `TimeModified`, get the maximum time, and add a concatenated form of that as the version number on top of my report. For instance:

Date fields are in `yyyyMMdd` format and time fields are in `mmhhss` format.
**ShopOrder:** 65642
**DateModified:** 20180118
**TimeModified:** 124500

**ShopOrder:** 65643
**DateModified:** 20180117
**TimeModified:** 142000

Since the `MAX(DateModified)` in these two shop orders is `20170118`, I want the `TimeModified` for that corresponding date: `124500`.

So the version number would look like this: **v0118.1245**.

I would like to, if possible, have this done in SSRS and not have to do much in my `dataset`, but that is not written in stone. I just want the MAX(Time) for THE MAX(Date).

**EDIT 1:**
This is what I've already tried:

```
LOOKUP(MAX(Fields!DateModified.Value), Fields!DateModified.Value, MAX(Fields!TimeModified.Value), "ShopOrders")
```

I was pretty proud of myself for thinking of this, but that burned down quickly when I got an error that said I cannot use Aggregate functions in Lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use lookups in this case although I could be very wrong as I don't use lookups enough to know their limitations.

The way I would approach it would be to simply add a new column in your query results that combines your date and time columns. Then you could simply get the Max of that new column.

Comment: That definitely did the trick. The time field has no 0 appended before the hour for times before 12. So it is just 73000 instead 073000. So my substring of hours and minutes end up getting hmms instead of hhmm. But I can figure out a way around that. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @CrazyCucumber you should be able to use something like `RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', TimeField), 6)` for the time portion of that column.

Comment: @CBlack Thank you! I've done that before but as Alan mentioned, the tunnel vision is pretty strong today. Thanks

Comment: @CBlack `SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT(00, TimeModified) , 6) 1, 4)` Did the trick for me to get just hh and mm. Thanks for your help.